# List object in entity returns to previous state in spite of clearing it

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an entity "city" with an Object listed in it as follows:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "building", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@SortComparator(DocumentSelectionComparator.class)
@OrderBy("id")
private List<DocumentSelection> house;
//get set methods..
```

My problem is now that i want to clear the object at some point but it always return to the previous state in which it contains data. I´ve tried clearing the object and saving the entity but it still wont work.
This is what i´ve tried:

```
//1
city.setHouse(null)
cityRepository.save(city)

//2
house.clear();
city.setHouse(house)
cityRepository.save(city)
```

I suppose that its not working because the entity is beeing referenced somewhere else thus rewriting the changes.. maybe? if so how do i change that. I really need to clear that object.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your relation is bidirectional ( i can tell from the mappedBy), in this case to clear the list you are trying to terminate the relation and to do this you need to do it from the owning entity side not the nonowning entity side.

The side of the relation with the mappedBy is the nonwoning entity so you need to remove the relation from DocumentSelection side.

To do so you need to iterate over your list , then remove the current object from that list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use orphan removal feature.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "building", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
```

and then call

```
city.getHouse().clear()
cityRepository.save(city)
```